# WSO2 IoT server connected cup sample data analytics throwing an exception

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-iot

I have imported the WSO2 IoT server Connected Cup sample device agent into Eclipse IDE, and disable device authentication for MQTT broker for easy of testing purpose. Then I created a connected cup sample device in the device management console, run the device agent, and expected to see some data in the analytics view. But nothing happened. When I took a look at the broker console it stated that the channel is established with the device, so I concluded that messages were normally transmitted from the device to the broker, and from the broker to the analytics server receiver. But then, I saw that the following exceptions were thrown in the analytics server console

[2017-04-04 14:55:29,918] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.indexing.AnalyticsDataIndexer} -  Error while looking up table Schema: [-1234:DEVICE_COFFEELEVEL_SUMMARY] does not exist
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.datasource.commons.exception.AnalyticsTableNotAvailableException: [-1234:DEVICE_COFFEELEVEL_SUMMARY] does not exist

and in  the core component console

[2017-04-04 14:55:29,927] [] ERROR - StandardWrapperValve Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path [/connectedcup] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unable to search the table - DEVICE_COFFEELEVEL_SUMMARY for tenant id : -1234 with query :  deviceId:t4l4gf267ara AND deviceType:connectedcup AND time : [1491306929 TO 1491310529].

It looks like that DEVICE_COFFEELEVEL_SUMMARY table is missing in the database or something like that. Any ideas what could be the reason for this fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could have happened if the summarization table is not created, You could trigger the table creation manually by running the spark script from the analytics console (https://ip:9444/carbon) [1].

In addition check whether the device has published data by going the data explorer in the console.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Scheduling+Batch+Analytics+Scripts